# Chrome doesn't send cookie back to server for iframe

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, cookies

I'm making a SPA with react router. With one route, I will have to show an authentication page from a third party via SAML 2.0 in a iframe. When the frame src is being loaded, the third party sets a cookie in iframe. However, Chrome doesn't send the cookie back received from the third party in iframe for following http requests in the same iframe.

It's really appreciated if someone could shed the light on why Chrome behaves totally different from other browsers, such as Firefox, Safari?

Comment: I'm noticing the same thing, just recently started to happen. All I can find is a recent 'SameSite' cookie feature that was added to chrome but I cannot see how that is stopping my iframed cookies from getting sent back.

Comment: You need to use HTTPS and set the cookie with samesite=none; and secure;